# Cython Memoryview compilation error

Tags: ubuntu, python-2.7, cython, memoryview

I am trying to get benefits of typed `Memoryview` on `Cython`, (Ubuntu 11.10 64bit)  but get compilation errors even in [this textbook example](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html). Without using `Memoryview` the generated code seems to compile ok. I'm working from Sage with Python 2.7 and get errors like:

`gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/sergey/Python/sage-5.5/local/include/csage -I/home/sergey/Python/sage-5.5/local/include -I/home/sergey/Python/sage-5.5/local/include/python2.7 -I/home/sergey/Python/sage-5.5/local/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/sergey/Python/sage-5.5/devel/sage/sage/ext -I/home/sergey/Python/sage-5.5/devel/sage -I/home/sergey/Python/sage-5.5/devel/sage/sage/gsl -I/home/sergey/.sage/sage_notebook.sagenb/home/admin/1/code -I/home/sergey/Python/sage-5.5/local/include/python2.7 -c _home_sergey__sage_sage_notebook_sagenb_home_admin_1_code_sage2_spyx_0.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_home_sergey__sage_sage_notebook_sagenb_home_admin_1_code_sage2_spyx_0.o -w -O2`

_home_sergey__sage_sage_notebook_sagenb_home_admin_1_code_sage2_spyx_0.c:2259:29: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘.’ token
_home_sergey__sage_sage_notebook_sagenb_home_admin_1_code_sage2_spyx_0.c:2261:44: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘.’ token

The suggested  fix:

```
import os
os.environ['LDFLAGS'] = '-march=i486'
os.environ['CFLAGS'] = '-march=i486'
```

did not help - it gave an error that my processor does not support such directives.

Thanks in advance,
Sergey